# Sybase: How to access to changed columns in an update trigger

Tags: triggers, sybase

I'm writing a trigger to get all changed columns after an update to a table. I think it's possible to fire the trigger when a particular field is changed. But that's not generic enough for my requirement. Can I do that by comparing the inserted and deleted table?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `trigger` for update!
And then check what columns were updated.

You can also compare the before (`deleted` table) and after (`inserted` table), but you have to see each column individually as well.

Comment: I have some difficulty using the column names in sys_columns table to loop through. Currently, I'm using trigger for update to check column by column manually. Not a good idea for a table with 50 cols :(

Answer (score 0):

When you say "not generic enough" it sounds as if you had it in mind to use triggers as a general means of finding out which columns in which tables changed when, and you want the method for some/many of your tables, which have various keys and fields.

aF is suggesting using the "for" (or after) trigger, and you can either compare inserted and deleted, or use the "if update(column-name)..." function.

If you want to genericise things, if I understand, I think that means you need to write some tool(s) that take a list of table(s) you configure as meta data somewhere and process them into triggers that do what you want (such as save the primary key content, table Id, and changed fields somewhere.)